# Why are my links on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, web, hyperlink

I'm developing the header section of a web project and I want to have links stuck at the top of it.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div id="header_section">

    <a class="toplink" href="#">Contact</a> 
    <a class="toplink" href="#">Register</a>
    <a class="toplink" href="#">Staff Login</a>  
    <a class="toplink" href="#">Home</a> 

    <h1 class="welsh"> SAMPLE </h1>
    <h1> SAMPLE </h1>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
a.toplink   
{
    font-family:        ‘Arial Narrow’, sans-serif;
    font-size:          12px;
    font-weight:        bold;

    position:           fixed;
    top:                0px;
    right:              10px;
    margin-right:       100px;

    padding:            6px;
    width:              100px;
    text-align:         center;

    color:              black;
    background-color:   #f3f3f3;
}
```

This has moved the links where I want them but they are all stacked on top of each when I want to display them next to each other. The only link displayed is 'Home' with the rest underneath. Any ideas?

Comment: add your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: yes. could you give us a jsfiddle.net live demo?

Comment: wht exactly do you need..........

Answer (score 1):

Your styles say take every link and position it 0px from top and 10px drom right and they will be position in one place.

to aboid it wrap links by div and set positioning to it not to links.

```
 <div id="header_section">
    <div class="links">
        <a class="toplink" href="#">Contact</a> 
        <a class="toplink" href="#">Register</a>
        <a class="toplink" href="#">Staff Login</a>  
        <a class="toplink" href="#">Home</a> 
    </div>    

    <h1 class="welsh"> SAMPLE </h1>
    <h1> SAMPLE </h1>
</div> 

.links {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 10px;
}

a.toplink   
{
    font-family:‘Arial Narrow’, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:100px;

    padding:6px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;

    color:black;
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, had an epiphany when I got back from lunch to do this and it was correct!

Answer (score 0):

add

```
div#header_section {
  display:inline;
}
```

or

```
div#header_section a {
  display:inline;
}
```

one of these should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change

```
position: fixed
```

To

```
position:related
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can change some code in your html and css part

as like this

**Css**

.toplink
{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
margin-right:100px;
padding:6px;
right:0;
width:700px;
text-align:center;
display:block;
}

```
.toplink li{
float:left;
}
.toplink a {
font-family:        ‘Arial Narrow’, sans-serif;
    font-size:          12px;
    font-weight:        bold;
    color:              black;
    margin-left:10px;
    background-color:   #f3f3f3;
    display:block;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header_section">

<ul class="toplink">   
    <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#">Register</a></li>
  <li>  <a href="#">Staff Login</a>  </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
</ul>

    <h1 class="welsh"> SAMPLE </h1>
    <h1> SAMPLE </h1>
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/n9UKF/2/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use:

```
position: absolute;
```

for the individual links. That will position them in the exact same place relative to their parent.

Use:

```
float:right;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mac_dempsey/FVFjG/19/).